# EXCEL macro to copy a BMP from EXCEL sheet to WORD Header

Tags: image, header

What is the EXCEL vba code to copy an image that is inserted in a specific tab of my EXCEL file,

then create and open a WORD file from scratch '(until this point the macro is working fine),

then paste it into the Header of the opened WORD file? '(I could copy it from excel but I am not able to paste it in WORD)

I need to add a code in the below, to paste the image into the Header of the opened WORD file.

Sub ExcelToWord()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim objWd As Object
Set objWd = CreateObject("word.application")

Dim myPath As String
Dim folderPath As String

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
myPath = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

objWd.Visible = True

Dim objDoc As Object
Set objDoc = objWd.Documents.Add

objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 0 '  portrait = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.UsedRange.Copy
objDoc.Content.Paste

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Select
Selection.Copy

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub